# ASCII character ranges using for loop

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, ascii

How do I cover the range of all letters lowercase a-z & uppercase A-Z using a for loop? Currently I have:

```
public static boolean isJavaIdentifierStart (char c) {

  if (c == 'a') { //how do I cover the range of all lowercase letters with a for loop?
    return true;
    } if (c=='Z') { //how do I cover all uppercase letters with a for loop?
      return true;
    } else if (c == '_') {
      return true;
    } else if (c == '$') {
      return true;
    } else
      return false;
  }        
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want to use a `for` loop. This can be done with simple comparisons `c>='a' && c<='z'` and then the same for capital letters, or you can use [Character#isLetter(char)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(char)). Also there is a method Character#isJavaIdentifierStart(char) which looks like exactly what you need.

Comment: This code is probably missing a closing `}` after the first `return true;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If would be much easier to test with the `>=` and `<=` operators:

```
if( c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' ) { 
   // do something
}
```

You don't actually need to test all of the values in the range, just make sure `c` falls inside it somewhere. You can do something similar for uppercase letters.

In fact you can simplify your method into a single `return` statement:

```
public static boolean isJavaIdentifierStart (char c) {
   return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') ||
          (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') ||
          (c == '_')             || 
          (c == '$');
}
```

However, I don't believe that Java identifiers can start with `$`, so your method is incorrect.

Comment: "However, I don't believe that Java identifiers can start with $, so your method is incorrect." The `Character` [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierStart(char)) would disagree.

Comment: Hmm, didn't know that. Thanks for the comment. Not sure I have ever seen that used in practice .

Comment: True, I am trying to replicate isJavaIdentifierStart(char) with my own method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess what you want, but you could use:

```
for(char c = 'a'; c < 'z'; c++) {
        System.out.println(c);
}
```

Edit to your comment:

Use this expression: `(c >= 'a' && c <= 'Z')` and similiar for range-
checking.

This works since `char` is a 16 bit unsigned integer, and therefore can be use in calculations.

Comment: or use for(char i='a'; i <= 'z'; i++){
        }

Comment: If c equals to values between a-z character and A-Z character it should return true.